# How to validate a form that creates multiple records

Tags: haskell, ihp

### Context

I have a view with a form with an arbitrary number of inputs that are dynamically generated by a controller. When the form is submitted, each input should create its own record, so that if there are 60 inputs then 60 records should be made.

### Question

How should one validate each of the inputs/fields? In the examples in the IHP documentation, only 1 record is created by a single form so I am not sure what is the best or idiomatic way to do this.

Possibly I could map a function like the following to every submitted input, but the Left case would be triggered by the first validation failure rather than all validation failures so I would need to save each failure in a list (?) before redirecting to the previous form view.

```
 action CreatePostAction = do
    let post = newRecord @Post
    post
        |> fill @'["title", "body"]
        |> validateField #title nonEmpty
        |> validateField #body nonEmpty
        |> ifValid \case
            Left post -> render NewView { post }
            Right post -> do
                post <- post |> createRecord
                setSuccessMessage "Post created"
                redirectTo PostsAction
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    action CreatePostAction = do
        let titles :: [Text] = paramList "title"
        let bodys :: [Text] = paramList "body"

        let posts = zip titles bodys
                |> map (\(title, body) -> newRecord @Post
                        |> set #title title
                        |> set #body body
                        |> validateField #title nonEmpty
                        |> validateField #body nonEmpty
                    )

        validatedPosts :: [Either Post Post] <- forM posts (ifValid (\post -> pure post))

        case Either.partitionEithers validatedPosts of
            ([], posts) -> do
                createMany posts
                setSuccessMessage "Post created"
                redirectTo PostsAction

            (invalidPosts, validPosts) -> render NewView { posts }
```

For that to work you need a view like this:

```hs
module Web.View.Posts.New where
import Web.View.Prelude
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes as A

data NewView = NewView { posts :: [Post] }

instance View NewView where
    html NewView { .. } = [hsx|
        <nav>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href={PostsAction}>Posts</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New Post</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <h1>New Post</h1>

        <form id="main-form" method="POST" action={CreatePostAction}>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            {forEach posts renderForm}
        </form>
    |]

renderForm :: Post -> Html
renderForm post = [hsx|
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            Title
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value={get #title post} class={classes ["form-control", ("is-invalid", isInvalidTitle)]}/>
        {titleFeedback}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            Body
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="body" value={get #body post} class={classes ["form-control", ("is-invalid", isInvalidBody)]}/>
        {bodyFeedback}
    </div>
|]
    where
        isInvalidTitle = isJust (getValidationFailure #title post)
        isInvalidBody = isJust (getValidationFailure #body post)

        titleFeedback = case getValidationFailure #title post of
            Just result -> [hsx|<div class="invalid-feedback">{result}</div>|]
            Nothing -> mempty

        bodyFeedback = case getValidationFailure #body post of
            Just result -> [hsx|<div class="invalid-feedback">{result}</div>|]
            Nothing -> mempty
```

My `NewPostAction` looks like this:

```hs
    action NewPostAction = do
        let post = newRecord
        let posts = take (paramOrDefault 2 "forms") $ repeat post
        render NewView { .. }
```

Comment: What does `[Either Post Post]` do? Also,`createMany posts`? (I couldn't find anything for `createMany` in IHP API docs.) My record type has 3 fields so I am trying to adapt your solution for that. I can use `zip3` in CreatePostAction, and there are no errors, but the records are not created. So I am trying to understand how your solution works.

Comment: Regarding the `[Either Post Post]`, the `ifValid` returns a `Left post` when it's an invalid post (e.g. no title) or a `Right post` when the post is valid. Therefore we have a list of Either (Left and Right values) and when there's a `Left post` we know that some validation has failed and we need to re-render the form.

The `createMany` does a multi-insert. It's a more efficient way of doing `forEach posts (\post -> createRecord post)` https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/database.html#creating-many-records

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I understand now. And I completely missed the `createMany` reference in the guide. However, why would adding a 3rd field prevent records from being created? After using zip3, I'm pattern matching like `|> map (\(title, body, score)` and no errors are shown.

Comment: Really silly mistake on my part... In my CreatePostAction, `let scores :: [Text] = paramList "scores"` had "scores" in the plural. After changing that to "score" everything works as expected.

Comment: I wasn't able to edit the answer, however `value={get #title post}` should be changed to `value="{get #title post}"` to prevent a compile error.